# Visibility of Class members?

Tags: c++, scope, visibility

I think i'm aware of accessibilty but I'm not sure if I understand visibility very clearly

For example:

```
class X
{
   int x;
};
```

Here, 'x' is only visible in class and but accessible outside of class. If I'm correct, Can someone explain the text in that *answer* about how visibility is not controlled etc..?

> (C++03/11.0) It should be noted that it is access to members and base classes that
>   is controlled, not their visibility. Names of members are still
>   visible, and implicit conversions to base classes are still
>   considered, when those members and base classes are inaccessible. The
>   interpretation of a given construct is established without regard to
>   access control. If the interpretation established makes use of
>   inaccessible member names or base classes, the construct is
>   ill-formed.

Comment: You should instead ask for clarification in that answer's comments.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: I'll just remove the reference to that answer from my question.

Comment: Um.. that's sort of the opposite of what I suggested is the right thing to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps this example helps:

```
class Bob
{
private:
    int foo(int, int);
};

class David : Bob
{
    void goo() {
        int a = foo(1, 2);  // #1
    }
};

class Dani : Bob
{
     void foo();
     void goo() {
         int a = foo(1, 2); // #2
     }   
};
```

On line #1, the name `foo` is *visible*, but the function which it names is not *accessible* (on account of being private to `Bob`). This is a compilation error, but the compiler knows that there is a potential function `Bob::foo` that would match, but isn't accessible.

On line #2, the name `foo` only refers to `Dani::foo`, while `Bob::foo` is *not visible* (because it is *hidden*), and so there is simply no matching function for the call `foo(1, 2)`. This is also a compilation error, but this time the error is that there is no matching function at all for the call.

Comment: Can I know what confusion might it cause?

Comment: @user1086635 not sure what you mean here: The line numbers simply do not match up to the description. Line #1 is "Class Bob" but he seems to mean "int foo(int, int);" and Line #2 is "{." The wording needs editing.

Comment: @Serodis: The references are to the lines marked with the comments `// #1` etc. This annotation style is common practice here on SO, since source blocks do not have any other form of readily visible numbering.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Can you tell me about what does it mean by `and implicit conversions to base classes are still considered` from that quoted text in question? Thanks.

Comment: @user1086635: If you had a function `void f(Bob&)`, and you would try to pass it with a `David` object, then the implicit conversion `David->Bob` would be selected. Since `Bob` is a private base class of `David`, this (implicit) conversion is inaccessible even thought the base class is visible.

Answer (score 7):

C++ has some esoteric feature concerning private class member names visibility and accessibility. By definition, a private class member name is only accessible by the class members and friends. However the rule of visibility can confuse many. They can be summarized as follows.

1. A private member's name is only accessible to other members and friends.
2. A private member is visible to all code that sees the class's definition. This means that its parameter types must be declared even if they can never be needed in this translation unit...
3. Overload resolution happens before accessibility checking.

> In C++ today ("C++03" and earlier variants), the notions of accessibility and visibility are
>   independent. Members of classes and namespaces are visible whenever they are "in
>   scope" and there is no mechanism to reduce this visibility from the point of declaration.
>   Accessibility is only a parameter for class members and is orthogonal to the notion of
>   visibility. This latter observation is frequently surprising to novice C++ programmers. See this [PDF](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2006.pdf).

Consider the following example.

```
#include < complex>

class Calc 
{ 
    public: 
        double Twice( double d ); 
    private: 
        int Twice( int i ); 
        std::complex Twice( std::complex c ); 
};

int main() 
{ 
    Calc c; 
    return c.Twice( 21 ); // error, Twice is inaccessible 
}
```

When the compiler has to resolve the call to a function, it does three main things, in order:

- Before doing anything else, the compiler searches for a scope that
  has at least one entity named Twice and makes a list of candidates.
  In this case, name lookup first looks in the scope of Calc to see if
  there is at least one function named Twice; if there isn't, base
  classes and enclosing namespaces will be considered in turn, one at a
  time, until a scope having at least one candidate is found. In this
  case, though, the very first scope the compiler looks in already has
  an entity named Twice — in fact, it has three of them, and so that
  trio becomes the set of candidates. (For more information about name
  lookup in C++, with discussion about how it affects the way you
  should package your classes and their interfaces
- Next, the compiler performs overload resolution to pick the unique
  best match out of the list of candidates. In this case, the argument
  is 21, which is an int, and the available overloads take a double, an
  int, and a complex. Clearly the int parameter is the best match for
  the int argument (it's an exact match and no conversions are
  required), and so Twice(int) is selected.
- Finally, the compiler performs accessibility checking to determine
  whether the selected function can be called.

**Note that *accessibility* (defined by modifiers in C++) and *visibility* are independent. Visibility is based on the scoping rules of C++. A class member can be *visible* and *inaccessible* at the same time.**

Static members as an example are *visible* globally through out the running of your application but *accessible* only with regard to the modifier applied to them.

Answer (score 1):

As a note: when you declare a `class`, the scope is private by default (opposed to a `struct` where members are public by default.)

The variable member 'x' is only accessible by your class and its friends. No one else can ever access 'x' directly (it can indirectly if you have a function returning a reference to it, which is a really bad idea.)

The text you quoted talks about visibility to the compiler, so `X::x` exists, no matter what. It won't *disappear* just because it's private. The visibility is used to find the member you are referencing and the first that matches is returned. At that point the compiler checks the accessibility, if accessible, you're all good. If not it is *ill-formed*.

Note that I mentioned friends. That keyword makes all variable members accessible. When the compiler deals with a friends, it completely ignores all the protected and private keywords.

In most cases, that's a very easy process. It goes in order. Period.

Where it becomes more complicated is when you start using virtual functions: these can be made public, protected, and private and that can change depending on the class declaration... (A derives from B and makes a protected virtual function public; it's generally not a good idea, but C++ doesn't prevent you from doing so.) Of course this only applies to functions, not variable members, so that's a different subject.

Answer (score 0):

That accessability and visibility are independet confuses especially in such situations:

```
class A
{
public:
  void Foo(int i){
  }
};

class B : public A
{
private:
  void Foo(){
  }
};

int main(){
    B b{};

    b.Foo(12);
}
```

Programmers from other languages would expect that `A::Foo(int)` would be callable because it is public. The point here is, that the private `B::Foo` hides the inherited proc.

This can be solved with a using declaration `using A::Foo`. But it becomes really hard in this sitation:

```
class A
{
public:
  void Foo(int i){
  }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
  using A::Foo;
private:
  void Foo(){
  }
};


class C : public B
{
public:
  using B::Foo;
private:
  void Foo(char c){
  }
}

int main(){
    B b{};

    b.Foo(12);
}
```

Using requires that there is NO private function. AFAIK the best way to solve it is to use some prefixes / suffixes for private or protected functions (like do_XXX() or do_XXX_internal).

In the STL private members are usually prefixed by a single underscore (these are reserved identifiers).